# How to get this type of font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I was not able to get the required font as shown below

[image]

Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[10.0pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[top=0.5cm,bottom=1.4cm,left=1.0cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage[portuges, brazil, english]{babel}   
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage{multicol}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=green]

 \centering
 \fontsize{8}{22}\selectfont
 \Huge\textbf{Organic Field Effect Transistor}
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{document}
```

The output of my MWE is 
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `\sffamily` and/or `\textsf`?

Comment: The letter font is shown above @Johannes_B

Comment: You are showing a sans serif font. To get a sans serif font, use `\sffamily` or `\textsf{}`. To find out which specific font that is, you are in the wrong spot. This is off-topic here.

Comment: You can compile the code and you will get to know @Johannes_B

Comment: It could be Nimbus Sans though.

Comment: You didn't even bother to provide a minimal example. I don't know what the question is you are asking.

Comment: I was not exactly able to produce the font image i have shown above only, i am not familiar with font series@Johannes_B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68575/discussion-between-biki-teron-and-johannes-b).

Comment: `\sffamily` is what you are looking for. Or Nimbus Sans (Probably) as the specific font.

Comment: The `times` package is deprecated. Use `mathptmx` or `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead. `\fontsize{8}{22}\selectfont` is both meaningless and useless because you change the font to `\Huge` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below tag may help you:

```
\documentclass[10.0pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[top=0.5cm,bottom=1.4cm,left=1.0cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage[portuges, brazil, english]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{times}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=green]

 \centering
 \fontsize{8}{22}\selectfont
 \Huge\textsf{\textbf{Organic Field Effect Transistor}}
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{document}
```

I've added the package "`times`" and the tag `\textsf` in your code.

Comment: HI :-) `times` is obsolete as you can seen at this link: https://ctan.org/pkg/times. You can substitute it with `newtxtext` package.